# Error connecting to Firebase from iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I can’t connect to my database. I followed all the steps and I even had to recreate it. Anyone had any similar issues or know how to resolve this?

```
2023-01-28 14:01:09.944917-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5617783] 10.5.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at posts/28617F89-5600-4E0B-9963-F52868E00FB9 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
[NewPostForm] Cannot create post: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}
```

These are the other error messages in the console above.

```
2023-01-28 14:00:55.393987-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5616856] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2023-01-28 14:00:55.394271-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5616856] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2023-01-28 14:00:55.397519-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5616856] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2023-01-28 14:01:00.551653-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5616856] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
2023-01-28 14:01:09.941788-0600 Socialcademy[18298:5617783] 10.5.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (132d74508) Stream error: 'Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions.'
```

I set up my Firebase database and brought in the right packages onto Xcode. Following all the steps, the Firebase was ready to go. When I ran my app, the error messages popped up, and the database was unresponsive to the action.

I initialized my Firebase:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct SocialcademyApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PostsList()
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried to connect to my database:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct PostsRepository {
    static let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
    
    static func create(_ post: Post) async throws {
        let document = postsReference.document(post.id.uuidString)
        try await document.setData(from: post)
    }
}

private extension DocumentReference {
    func setData<T: Encodable>(from value: T) async throws {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            try! setData(from: value) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your rules

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: There is a link in Firebase/Firestore and if you google Firestore rules you will find a ton of information in the documentation,

Comment: The above comment is likely the culprit. By default, you cannot read or write without being authenticated. So, authenticate and you will likely be on your way.

Comment: I changed it from ...if false to ...if timestamp ..... Will that work?